# Cannot Reboot or Shutdown Ubuntu server

Tags: server, shutdown

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and its been running fine.

I went to update as initial screen said xx Packages can be updated.
I did this and upgraded.

I did a reboot and it just hangs on the shutdown screen with the final bit saying:

```
[ok] Stopped target Network is Online.
```

And it just hangs here.

I can force shutdown.

Upon reboot I log in and get xx Packages can be updated.

So I run `sudo apt update` and also `sudo apt upgrade` but it says everything is up to date and it still wont reboot.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: First thing to do is use `sudo apt full-upgrade` instead of just upgrade. That assures all the packages are updated.

Comment: `upgrade` only allows minor upgrades for stability purposes; apps/programs cannot jump to the next version so you restricted the upgrades that can be installed. `dist-upgrade` is the next level of upgrade...

Comment: Hi MichaelBay and guiverc I have tried both your suggestions and still get the same response, both say "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded"